# Is it possible to know whether the copied content in clipboard is mp3 file using awt.Toolkit and Clipboard in java

Tags: java, swing, awt, clipboard, background-process

I am trying to write a code which runs at *background* and *monitors* the copy actions for copying a **.mp3** *file* or a *folder containing* a **.mp3** file

```
{

            Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        if (cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor))
         {
               try {
                String name = ""+cb.getData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
             boolean found = false;
                 if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3]"))
                     {
                                System.out.println("Is MP3");
                                found = true;
                             }


                 if (!found)
               {
                        System.out.println("Is not MP3");
                   }

                    }

           catch(UnsupportedFlavorException ex)
             {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
           catch(IOException ex)
             {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
         }

    }
```

Comment: *"or a folder containing a .mp3 file"*  Are you trying to implement Digital Rights Management?  What is this for?

Comment: not DRM has some disadvantages... i am working on audio piracy protection project for my study...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes.  You need to check the `Clipboard` contents to see if it supports the `DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor` `DataFlavor`.  If it does, you need to iterate over the contents (which is `java.util.List` of `File`s) and make a determination of the content.

The following only checks to see if the files are `.mp3` files (by checking the name extension), but it wouldn't be hard to check for `isDirectory` and do a recursive check of the directory...

```
Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
if (cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
    try {
        List files = (List) cb.getData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
        boolean found = false;
        for (Object o : files) {
            if (o instanceof File) {
                File f = (File) o;
                if (f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    System.out.println("I haz MP3");
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("I notz haz MP3");
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx i wil use it and check for it... MadProgrammer

Comment: error: for-each not applicable to expression type `for(Object o :files)`

Comment: `String name = ""+cb.getData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
 boolean found = false;                if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3]"))` i have changed ur code like this i dnt knw this is the correct way to code but it works...

Comment: 1- for-each loops are available in Java 6+. 2- as shown in the example cb.getData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor) returns a java.util.List, you can't make it a String

Comment: but its considering as java.awt.List

Comment: got it... imported the right things... works file will check for the directory

Comment: can we get informed with an event that the contents of clipboard are changed of the same flavor.

Comment: No - Think about it, the flavour hasn't changed.  What you could do is, when the flavour does change, add something else to the clipboard AFTER you've pulled what you want from it...

Comment: we have no concern when the flavor is changed, as we are interested in   just files and directories and clipboard is to be kept unchanged unless it contains .mp3 file is copied. i am trying to keep the block of code which checks whether the copied data contains mp3 to be executed when ever the clipboard contents are changed with the new files or folders copied

Comment: Yeah, what I would do is, when you detect a flavour change of `javaFileListFlavor`, I would pull the content from the clipboard and then replace the clipboard content with something else, like a `String` for example.  This will ensure that you will be notified of the next time it changes to `javaFileListFlavor`

Comment: yeah i got ur idea. but the user will be unhappy when hes just copying files other than .mp3 each time my program wil change the content into  string... is there a way that i can copy clipboard contents in another object of clipboard and implement ur idea on that not affecting the original clipboard object

Comment: The only thing you could do is maintain a `Timer` of some kind and check the contents of the clipboard...little dirty, but it's the best you can do next to having the user actually use some action...

Comment: ya.. thank u for guiding u r a good teacher,,, its hard to seek help here on stackoverflow with no reputation... i wil check for ur ideas and lets see if i come up with some thing...

Comment: As you informed I have tried replacing the clipboard by string but now it notifies twice that is 1. when we copy something to clipboard and 2. when we change the content to string. but I need to be notified once during the first time not when I change that to string

Comment: I guess the Timer strategy is the last option :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468802(v=vs.85).aspx

Using native windows C function and user JNA(Java native access library) to complete your requirement.
JNA:
https://github.com/twall/jna

Comment: :) I think your solution is better, but for me I trust windows API more than the awt which I'm not familiar with...

Comment: *"I trust windows API more than the awt.."*  For OS X and *nix, I'll trust the AWT every time.  ;)

Comment: i am good at AWT than WINDOWS API that is why i have selected JAVA as my language