# Get Local Clipboard contents

Tags: java, native, clipboard, jna

I there I am interested in accessing the clipboard data using a Java program, and I am aware of the method using awt:

```
String contents = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

However this doesn't work for my purposes because the clipboard I am trying to access the data from appears to be a local to the specific application that Ctrl C's.

Is there any way I can access another applications 'local' clipboard?

I believe the DataFlavour to be :

flavor java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-text-encoding;representationclass=[B]
  class: [B]
  mime : application/x-java-text-encoding; class="[B"

but I'm not sure how to create a DataFlavor or w.e in order to actually read the data?

Comment: You need to know the `DataFlavor` of the data you are trying get from the clipboard, this will determine in what the data is returned to you and what you will need to do in order to get it

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798646/can-java-system-clipboard-copy-a-file/31798747#31798747) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602950/is-it-possible-to-know-whether-the-copied-content-in-clipboard-is-mp3-file-using/22603155#22603155)

Comment: how could I find this out? I don't get an unsupported flavor exception when using the stringFlavor I just get the clipboard contents of Ctrl C's make outside of the foreign application who's clipboard contents I actually want.

Comment: Ok I found the DataFlavor but I'm not sure how to get/use it?

Comment: It will depend on the DataFlavor, the determines the actual object which is returned

Comment: It's flavor java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-text-encoding;representationclass=[B] class: [B] mime : application/x-java-text-encoding; class="[B"

Comment: I tried using :
 `DataFlavor myFlav = new DataFlavor("application/x-java-text-encoding;class=\"[B\";charset=Cp1252");
       byte[] b = (byte[]) t.getTransferData(myFlav);
       Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(b), "Cp1252");

       System.out.println("PRIMARY TYPE: " + df[i].getPrimaryType());
       StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
       char[] c = new char[1];
       while (r.read(c) != -1)
        s.append(c);
       System.out.println("The stuff: " + new String(s));`
 but all i get printed is "Cp1252"

Comment: I'm starting to think it's not a DataFlavor issue, it seems like the application has its own clipboard and won't let me access it's contents.

Comment: I'd start by trying to copy something from notepad which should just be a string data flavor

Comment: I have already successfully gotten clipboard contents from notepad using the original code from my question

Comment: Like if you Ctrl + C inside the application and try to Ctrl + V outside the application you don't get what you copied, and that leads me to believe it will be impossible for my program to access it as well.